# Table view repeating data in each section

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view with a number of sections. When i add the data in a plist, they add to the correct sections but when the table gets displayed it looks something like this;

Table View:

```
Section 1
  Note 1

Section 2
  Note 1
  Note 2
```

instead of note 1 in section one and note 2 in section 2.

I presume its in the celForRowAtIndexPath where the mistake is but I dont know what.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
cell.textLabel.text = [[self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Date"];
}
```

Update - NSLog of self,notes:

```
{ Category = Section 1; 
Date = "December 9, 2013"; 
Text = "Note 1 text"; 
Title = "Note 1"; }, 

{ Category = Section 2;
 Date = "December 9, 2013";
 Text = "Note 2 text";
 Title = "Note 2"; 
}
```

Plist link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrbfh.png

Comment: show nslog of `self.notes` Array.

Comment: How your self.notes data looks like?

Comment: self.notes is exactly as I expect it to be - please see update

Comment: Your `self.notes` not have the structure to show in section tableview.

Comment: It does because ive used a predicate in numberOfRowsInSection that takes the category key from the note and assigns it to that section

Comment: see my answer It show how array structure you should have

Comment: Note that `indexPath` consists of two parts: section and row.  It's not clear how you can get data for multiple sections when you don't examine the section value.

Comment: hi, Bhumeshwer katre please see the link i added for the structure, im a little confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        if (indexPath.section == 0){
            NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Category =[cd] %@", @"Category 1"];
            NSArray * catArray = [self.notes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
            cell.textLabel.text = [[catArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[catArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Date"];

        } else if (indexPath.section == 1){
            NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Category =[cd] %@", @"Category 1"];
            NSArray * catArray = [self.notes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
            cell.textLabel.text = [[catArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[catArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Date"];
        } 
    }
```

The last NSPredictate parameter, for example: @"Category 1", should be controller by your app logic if you want to make it depends on user.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show data in table section then your array structure should be like that.
Then no need of any hard coded comparison.

```
( 
  (
    {key value pair}, 
    {key value pair}
  ),
  (
   {key value pair}, 
   {key value pair} 
  ), 
  ( 
   {key value pair}, 
   {key value pair}, 
   {key value pair}, 
   {key value pair}, 
   {key value pair}
  )
)
```

then access in such way:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[[self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Title"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the section into account in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (indexPath.section == 0){
        cell.textLabel.text = [[self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]     objectForKey:@"Date"];

    } else if (indexPath.section == 1){
    // do stuff speficic for section 1 (the second section)
    // ... 

    } 
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, but 2 sections was just an example, the number of sections can change depending on the user, so hard coding the conditions for each section will be hard

Comment: @user3001526 - Your `notes` object should be an array of arrays.  The outer array contains one entry per section, while the inner array contains the entries for a single section.

Comment: This is slightly confusing me, could you please explain?

Comment: There is one NSArray that contains the information for your sections. So the count of objects in this array is the number of secants. Then you need to to add rows to each section. So this NSArray contains other NSArrays. Inside these nested arrays you will find the actual data for each row. In cellForRowAtIndexPath: you could then do something like: NSArray * sectionArray = [self.secions objectAtIndex: indexPath.section]; Then to get the info for the row: YourDataObject * dataObj = [sectionArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]; Then use dataObj to get the data to populate the cell.